# JQuery get all nodes of ID and Class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have this element:

[image]

and I want to hide every child of this.

So far I tried this:

```
var children = $('#OpenLayers.Layer.Markers_41').children();
children.each(function(){
    $(this).css('visibility','hidden');
});
```

But I can not get the specific element with this.
How do I do this?

Comment: Why not just apply the css rule to `OpenLayers` div instead of applying to all its children ? Also it would be good if you can post your actual HTML instead of providing a link to the image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.` in a selector is used to specify a class. If you have `.` in the ID, you need to escape it so it will be treated literally.

```
var children = $('#OpenLayers\\.Layer\\.Markers_41').children();
```

For this reason, it's a bad idea to use characters that have special meaning in CSS selectors (`#`, `.`, and `:`) in IDs and classes.

It's also not necessary to use `.each()`. jQuery update methods automatically map over all the elements in a collection.

```
$('#OpenLayers\\.Layer\\.Markers_41 > *').css('visibility', 'hidden');
```